# woocommerce store api + reactjs - add to cart not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a react app Im working on to create a new frontend for an already live woocommerce site. I'm using this endpoint `/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item` like so -

```
    let config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8010/proxy/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item",
    data: {
      id : id,
      quantity: 1,
      variation: [
{
  attribute: "Color",
  value: color,
},
{
  attribute: "Size",
  value: size,
}
      ]
    }
    }
    console.log(config)
   const resp = await axios(config).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
```

Which is giving me a successful json response showing I have the item added -
`items_count: 1`

Then I have a cart component to api call and render -

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, []);

const getCart = async () => {
    let config = {
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:8010/proxy/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart"
    }
   await axios(config).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
  });
  }
```

However when navigating to this page/component or any other, the api call is returning an empty cart - `items_count: 0`

On the checkout page I tried using a different endpoint `wp-json/wc/store/v1/checkout` but this is giving me an error -
`code: "woocommerce_rest_cart_empty" data: {status: 400} message: "Cannot create order from empty cart."`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the request isn't setting a cookie which will prevent the cart from working as expected.  In my experience, I can make a build of my React app and activate it as a WordPress theme. Then the add-to-cart works as expected.  But if I'm using the live preview of the app instead, the add-to-cart will not work because the cookie is missing.  Here's a GitHub issue about it.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/issues/5683